# Altera JTAG: No device found

Tags: intel-fpga, jtag

I got a task to create a custom board from DE0-Nano dev board. So I used EP4CE22E22C6N as similar chip for hand soldering. But when we ordered USB Blaster, Quartus says No device found.

I try the JTAG connector (top right in schematic) with all MSEL pins tied to GND. I just want to know how to find if the USB Blaster is bad or the schematic is wrong (I bet this since it's my first FPGA schema).

Is the schematic ok or does it need changes to get it working? Also is there a way to test if the Altera chip or the programmer is ok? I don't care for the memory at the moment.

Here is my schematic, VCCA is 2.5V and VCCD_PLL is 1.2V:

[image: My schemaof Altera FPGA]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During searching for solution I found that when MSEL pins are set to Active serial (AS) then after connecting to power without programmer the pin DCLK should start generate clock signal for FLASH memory.

When I measured the DCLK no signal appeared. After resoldering the fpga I was able to detect it and upload the program to it. I don't know if the solderin or the fpga was bad.

So the schematic is good for programming (I haven't tried flash programming yet).